# Was Charity Burbage's name mentioned before her death?

Tags: harry-potter

Charity Burbage, a member of the Hogwarts staff, dies quite late in the series. Were either of her names ever used in the books prior to the chapter where she dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sole mention of Charity Burbage is in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*.

A quick scan of all seven novels shows that no mention is made of either the name Charity or the surname Burbage prior to this novel.

[image: search results]

Comment: @J.Mini - I have ebook versions of all seven novels and can use the [quality check plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125428) on [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) to find [any particular word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e7bc.png).

Comment: Smart! I've accepted.